How to have interactions with right mouse click as well as brush in d3
I have a scatterplot with a tooltip interaction on the points using the right mouse button. On top of it I added a 2D brush, it works perfectly, but I cannot iniziate brushing if I am on a datapoint because it will catch the event and not send it to the brush. I tried to swap the order of the components but at that point I have the other problem around, now my points never receive the mouse event.
